# customising multiple if statements in java

Tags: java

I have the below if statements check which looks not correct to me as they are multiple if's check please advise how can i reduce them as since looking technically also multiple if checks is been done

```
String incomingProduct = brokerInvoice.getProduct();
if (incomingProduct!= null &&  incomingProduct.equalsIgnoreCase("CD") ) {
    brokerInvoice.setSourceSystem((String)configuration.getConfiguration().get("CD"));
}
if (incomingProduct!= null &&  incomingProduct.equalsIgnoreCase("COMMODITY") ) {
    brokerInvoice.setSourceSystem((String)configuration.getConfiguration().get("CQD"));
}
if (incomingProduct!= null &&  incomingProduct.equalsIgnoreCase("DITY") ) {
    brokerInvoice.setSourceSystem((String)configuration.getConfiguration().get("DITY"));
}
if (incomingProduct!= null &&  incomingProduct.equalsIgnoreCase("ITY") ) {
    brokerInvoice.setSourceSystem((String)configuration.getConfiguration().get("ITY"));
}
if (incomingProduct!= null &&  incomingProduct.equalsIgnoreCase("CO") ) {
    brokerInvoice.setSourceSystem((String)configuration.getConfiguration().get("CO"));
}
if (incomingProduct!= null &&  incomingProduct.equalsIgnoreCase(MODITY") ) {
    brokerInvoice.setSourceSystem((String)configuration.getConfiguration().get("MODITY"));
}
```

Folks please advise if I can use map data structure here

Comment: Isn't it a bit redundant to do the null check *every* time? Then again, that code is nothing but redundancy.

Comment: I sincerely hope you don't work as a programmer.

Comment: Is that a copy-paste bug you have in handling `"COMMODITY"`? It uses the `"CD"` configuration line in the line above

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] products = new String[6]

products[0] = "CD";
products[1] = "COMMODITY";
products[2]= "DITY";
products[3] = "IT";
products[4] = "CO";
products[5] = "MODITY";

for(int i = 0; i < products.length; i++){
    if (incomingProduct!= null &&  incomingProduct.equalsIgnoreCase(products[i]) ) {
        brokerInvoice.setSourceSystem((String)configuration.getConfiguration().get(products[i]));
    }
}
```

This should work and be more readable

Comment: `String[] products= {"CD", "CO", "COMMODITY", "DITY", "ITY", "MODITY"};`

Answer (score 0):

Optimal variant:

```
if (incomingProduct!= null) {
        switch(incomingProduct.toLowerCase()){
             case "cd":  doSomethingWithProduct(incomingProduct.toUpperCase());
                     break;
             case "commodity":  doSomethingWithProduct(incomingProduct.toUpperCase());
                     break;
        }
    }

doSomethingWithProduct(String name){
    brokerInvoice.setSourceSystem((String)configuration.getConfiguration().get(name));
}
```

Comment: actually you should remove the breaks and call doSomethingWithProduct(incomingProduct.toUpperCase()); for all cases

Comment: actually no because it won't do anything if incomingProduct is "foo" for example

Comment: if you check the question, it is always the same thing so no need to make it more complex than it should, otherwise it is confusing and doesn't help much

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you can avoid checking that the `incomingProduct` is in `{"CD", "CO", "COMMODITY", "DITY", "ITY", "MODITY"}` you should simply write:

```
String incomingProduct = brokerInvoice.getProduct();    
if (incomingProduct != null) {    
    brokerInvoice.setSourceSystem((String) configuration.getConfiguration().get(incomingProduct));
}
```

Otherwise you may go with `doge`'s answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `"COMMODITY"` -> `"CQD"` case is deliberate:

```
private static final TreeMap<String, String> MAPPINGS = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
static {
    MAPPINGS.put("CD", "CD");
    MAPPINGS.put("COMMODITY", "CQD");
    MAPPINGS.put("DITY", "DITY");
    MAPPINGS.put("ITY", "ITY");
    MAPPINGS.put("CO", "CO");
    MAPPINGS.put("MODITY", "MODITY");
}

void doThings() {
    String incomingProduct = brokerInvoice.getProduct();
    if (incomingProduct != null) {
        String configKey = MAPPINGS.get(incomingProduct);
        if (configKey != null) {
            brokerInvoice.setSourceSystem((String) configuration.getConfiguration().get(configKey));
        }
    }
}
```